# Iterating and creating new anonymous types dynamically

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, anonymous-types

I have an anonymous type of this form:

```
new List<MyList>()
{
   new Column { Name = "blah", Width = 100, Hidden = true },
   new Column { Name = "blah1", Width = 60, Hidden = false }
}
```

How can I go about creating the content within the list dynamically, like:

```
new List<MyList>()
{
    foreach (var columns in col) 
    {
       new Column { Name = columns.Name ... }
    }
}
```

Even with col returning the right sort of data, the above example isn't acceptable and I can't see why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You try to loop over the collection inside the object initializer block (thx to Luke).

Try creating the list first and than filling it,

```
var list = new List<MyList>();

foreach (var columns in col) 
{
    list.Add(new Column { Name = columns.Name ... });
}
```

Comment: +1, but with a small nitpick: The code in the question isn't looping "inside the list constructor", it's looping inside an *object initializer* block. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, but have you tried something of the form:

```
col.Select(c => new Column {Name = c.Name ... etc}).ToList();
```

Comment: I thought this was what the poster was asking at first, but I think BeowulfOFs answer may be what Rio is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like

```
var theList = new List<MyList>();
col.ForEach(c=> theList.Add( new Column(){ Name=c.Name ... etc } ));
```